# Como hacer UPDATE sql 2 veces al mismo tiempo

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla con 2 campos; Uno se llama **|IdComentarios|** y otro **|IDUsuario|**. Les estoy pasando el siguiente código **SQL**:

```
<?php

    /* Si se presiona ENVIAR recogo lo que se ENVIO*/
if (isset($_GET['comentario'])){

    $sql = "UPDATE  contenidones SET IdComentarios = '$_GET[comentario]' WHERE ID = '$_GET[id]' "; 
    $sqx = "UPDATE  contenidones SET IDUsuario = '$_GET[comentario]' WHERE ID = '$_GET[id]' ";

    $resultado= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    
    if ($resultado == true){
        echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";
        echo "Tu comentario se a enviado, gracias";
        echo "</div>";
    }else{
        echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";
        echo "El comentario no pudo enviarse trata mas tarde";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    }
    /* ---*/
?>
```

Resulta que con la primera sentencia **$sql** sí se me actualizan los datos en el campo de la tabla **|IdComentarios|** pero en el de **|IDUsuario|** no pasa igual. Ya revisé y no es problema de comunicación. Es como si al hacer la primera consulta **$sql** el programa no hiciera la segunda **$sqx** (Aunque es lo mismo)

**Mi pregunta es**

Puedo actualizar con **UPDATE** y **SET** 2 campos al mismo tiempo?, Si es que SÍ, ¿Como?

Comment: deberias ejecutar el query para las dos Update (se llaman distinto)

mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
mysqli_query($conn,$sqx);

Comment: Jorge B; En efecto acabo de hacerlo y lo eh conseguido resolver como tu dices. Ahora el problema es que me esta pintando 2 valores en el echo repetidos de la primera sentencia (Estoy buscando el porque, muchas gracias...)

Comment: Fijate que el echo solo te imprimirá si se cumple el primer Update, ya que $resultado se refiere al primero. Que es lo que te imprime literalmente?

Comment: Jorge B Lo que esta pasando es que el campo |IdComentarios| tiene un TRIGGER de UPDATE al igual que |IDUsuario| entonces como hay una "DOBLE ACTUALIZACION" se registran 2 COMENTARIOS iguales y el mismo echo de los comentarios me los pinta... 

Alguna idea de como tener 2 TRIGGER en la misma tabla?

Comment: Puedes usar [`multi_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php), que te permite ejecutar varias consultas, es importante que termines cada una por `;` en ese caso. Aunque te recomiendo que uses consultas preparadas para prevenir ataques de *inyección SQL*.

Comment: y que recibe $_GET[comentario] que lo estas usando para actualizar el IDUsuario ?

Comment: Jorge B me estoy dando cuenta de que algo hice mal... Es que el  $_GET[comentario]  recibe un comentario de un formulario que redirecciona a la misma pagina (Esto no es tan relevante)

El punto es que yo utilizo un TRIGGER para actualizar el campo comentario sin darme cuenta de que cada vez que actualizo OJO : CUALQUIER CAMPO DE LA TABLA esta afectando a OTRA tabla sin querer... 

Entonces al tener 2 UPDATE se suben 2 comentarios IGUALES Porque el TRIGGER actua 2 veces porque afecta a toda la tabla... Significa que algo estoy estructurando mal o el tema del TRIGGER no esta bien...

Answer (score 0):

Independientemente del *trigger* que comentas, no entiendo el porque haces dos consultas a la misma tabla seguidas cuando lo puedes unificar en solo una de este modo:

```
$sql = "
  UPDATE  contenidones SET 
    IdComentarios = '$_GET[comentario]', 
    IDUsuario = '$_GET[comentario]' 
  WHERE ID = '$_GET[id]' ";
```

y quizás te ahorres el resto de problemas debido al **trigger**.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta (En realidad ayuda). Ya cambie la consulta y me estoy deshaciendo del trigger. Tenia el concepto de que el trigger solo afectaba 1 CAMPO y resulta que lo hace con TODA LA TABLA. Lo que estoy haciendo es crear una nueva consulta que INSERTA directamente los datos en lugar de actualizarlos con el TRIGGER y luego ya hago con ellos lo que necesito...

Hacia las 2 consultas porque estaba tratando de actualizar campos que iban a ACTUALIZAR por medio del TRIGGER campos en OOOotras tablas, pero  resulto una mala practica, por eso estoy cambiando el orden de las cosas...

Comment: Ok, bueno, me alegro que te sirva de algo. La verdad, yo nunca he usado triggers, primero porque desconocía su existencia, y después porque prefiero controlarlo todo desde PHP, aunque reconozco que seguramente sean útiles en determinadas ocasiones, pero ya soy muy viejo para cambiar mis costumbres en eso :-)  Si esta respuesta cumple con tu pregunta (cosa que dudo pues estás realizando más cambios) recuerda marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!

Comment: Los TRIGGER afectan a toda la tabla, no a campos específicos de la tabla, lo cual no quita que, dentro del TRIGGER puedas verificar el estado de un campo en concreto y a partir de ahí hacer o no algo desde el TRIGGER. Sea como sea, puede que el problema aquí esté a otro nivel: en el diseño mismo de las tablas o en la lógica que estás implementando para resolver tu problema. Sin conocer a fondo esos detalles es difícil encontrar cuál sería la solución más óptima a este problema, @SAGEX.